# How to make CMake path independent

Tags: c++11, cmake, linker

I have a project with the following CMake file:

```
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(mp3_tagger)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
find_package(Boost 1.67 COMPONENTS program_options filesystem REQUIRED)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS)

set(SOURCE_FILES src/main.cpp src/Parser.cpp include/Parser.h src/Tagger.cpp include/Tagger.h)
add_executable(mp3_tagger ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(mp3_tagger ${Boost_LIBRARIES} -L/usr/local/Cellar/taglib/1.11.1/lib -ltag)
```

I would want to make it work independently from where the library has been installed (essentially i want to remove the hard coded path `-L/usr/local/Cellar/taglib/1.11.1/lib`) so that the CMake could work on a different machine that might have the library in a different folder like it is for Boost.

Is there a way to do so or the only way would be to modify the file?

Comment: I don't quite understand, whether you are allowed to modify given `CMakeLists.txt`? If yes, you may create "Find" script for the `tag` library and use it similar to Boost. If no, you need to add appropriate `-L` flag outside of given file, which could be quite tricky (if even possible).

Comment: @Tsyvarev yes i can modify the ```CMakeLists.txt``` , i'm trying to find a way to remove the ```-L``` flag so that it could be compiled on a different machine that might have the library installed in a different folder

Comment: You need to write "Find" script. If you don't know where to start in that, then read corresponging [how-to](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/tutorials/How-To-Find-Libraries). If you are trying to write that file and are faced with specific problems, describe these problems.